# Ruby vs Python get request

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying to make a GET request to the NBA API in ruby. I've tried both the `unirest` library but the request hangs after 5 minutes.

When I use python's `requests` library for the same url + endpoint it works. Here's what I'm trying for each:

```
require "unirest"

base_url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats"
team_endpoint = "/teamgamelog"
params = {:TeamID => "1610612739", :Season => "2016-17", :SeasonType => "Playoffs"}

HEADERS = {'user-agent'=> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept'=> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
}

response = Unirest.get "#{base_url}#{team_endpoint}", headers: HEADERS, 
parameters: params
```

The above code doesn't work (the connection eventually times-out). The following python code works:

```
import requests

base_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
               'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),}
end_point = '/teamgamelog'
PARAMS = {'TeamID': '1610612739', 'Season': '2016-17', 'SeasonType': 'Playoffs'}

r = requests.get(base_url+end_point, headers=HEADERS, params=PARAMS)
```

Any advice on solving the ruby case?

Comment: Do you notice the endpoint in the case of both ? HINT: Look at the trailing slashes.

Comment: Yes, even after fixing that I'm getting the same result

Comment: Good! One less probable cause to think about. Now What about HEADERS part in ruby code ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add HEADERS in my post. The HEADERS that I declare is that following: `HEADERS = {'User-Agent'=> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept'=> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
  }`

Comment: Please update the code in the question too.

Comment: Yes will do. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me

Comment: Why did you choose [`unirest`](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/unirest)? That gem didn't get any updates in the last three years and has only about 75k downloads. Whereas well-known gems like `rest-client` or `faraday` have millions (both have more that 30M) of downloads, a bigger community and much better documentation.

Comment: There's no reason in particular. I tried the ruby port of python's requests package and I'm running into the same issue. I even tried using the `open-uri` library but that doesn't work either

Comment: Why are you using different headers in each case?

Comment: Also, I should mention like @spickermann alluded to, that as a rubyist I've never heard of unirest. Maybe it has some failings? Try the gems he mentioned first.

Comment: I used headers to see if there was a header that was missing from the ruby request. https://github.com/kshvmdn/nba.js/issues/16 this could be contributing to the issue btw!